# Where to add onsubmit to a form in Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, dom-events

In my HTML I've got a form *without* an `onsubmit` event listener:

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post" id="contact">
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

As a result, the form is always posted whenever I click the "Send" button.  However, I'd like to validate the input first, so I'd like to attach an event listener and intercept the post.  This is how I attach the event listener to the form:

```
window.onload = function() {
    function validate() {
        return window.confirm("Confirm");
    }
    var form = document.getElementById("contact");
    form.addEventListener("submit", validate);
}
```

While the event listener is being executed, if I go by above approach the form is *always* posted!  However, if I make the `validate()` function global and use `onsubmit="return validate();"` in the `<form>` tag, then the form is only being submitted conditionally, as expected.

Why does this not work by adding the `validate()` function as above?  It seems the `false` return value gets lost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern event handling has a more complex API, it gives more flexibility but that comes at the cost of not being able to tie behaviour to a simple boolean result.

For your use case, you need to capture the event object:

```
function validate(ev) {
```

Then you can prevent the default action on it:

```
if (!confirm('Confirm')) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Hmm... I added the `ev.preventDefault();` and it works just fine.  Do I still need to return false?

Comment: No. You just call methods on the event object.

Comment: Thanks Quentin.  One more question though: why does the `return false` work when I attach it directly to the `<form>` and not so when I go through the `addEventListener()`.  Different ways of delivering/checking the events?

Comment: Yes. Old and limited vs. new and flexible.